# Matlab Convert structure refrence and values to variables

Tags: matlab, variables, dynamic, indexing, construct

I've been searching for about a day for this but couldn't find an answer for it.

What i want to do is to change this construct (solution of solve function):

```
 Fx3: [1x1 sym]
 Fy3: [1x1 sym]
Fyp3: [1x1 sym]
  u2: [1x1 sym]
  u3: [1x1 sym]
 up3: [1x1 sym]
  v3: [1x1 sym]
```

into this:
Fx3 = 495e+03
and so on.

also i have to mention that i can't simply enter the code to do it as all my sym variables used in solve function are generated dynamically. that's why i need a code to dynamically change all values into variables with index reference as its name.

so any ideas how it can be achieved? thanks in advance.

Comment: double(myStruct.Fx3) !?

Comment: double function can't be used on structures.

Answer (score 0):

For me the **double** function works perfectly fine.

```
>> stt.a=sym(1.2)

stt = 

    a: [1x1 sym]

>> double(stt.a)

ans =

    1.2000
```

for the whole structure you can do this:

```
stt.a = sym(1.2);
stt.b = sym(100);
stt.c = sym(0.02);

ff=fieldnames(stt);
for i=1:size(ff)
double(getfield(stt,ff{i}))
end
```

Comment: you know you should put stt.a in double function. what i want is to convert all values into doubles also assign each value as variable that has the same name in structure index reference. you see, what you get as output is ans, what i want is a=1.2000 as output

Comment: so you better update your code with a simple example and show what you want.

Comment: unfortunately, i can't add image to my post due to reputation system. but to put it simply, i need to change stt structure into series of variable such as variable 'a' that has the value of 1.2000.

Comment: actually, you can achieve that by structfun(@subs,stt) but since i need to change every single index into variables, that's where it gets tricky :| you put all into an array, i need them separately :|

for example as output i need a = 1.2 , b = 100 and c = 0.02 (all as variables)

Comment: @BabakDS Why are you fixated on individual variables? Why not use one matrix/cell/struct for the double values?

Comment: since i need to use the variables in another matrix to solve another equation. i need to know which variable and where to put it in equation.